# find modular multiplicative inverse

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

is it possible to find the solution of following:  9^(-1)%M  ie inverse of 9 modulo M  where 2<=M<=10^9 it may not be a prime and gcd(9,M) may not be 1  if not possible to find such a solution is there any method to solve:  ((10^n-1)/9)%M  1<=n<=10^16

Comment: What do you mean in the statement "solve: ((10^n-1)/9)%M 1<=n<=10^16"? Solve for what? Is there an equation involving `M` and `n` that you have in mind?

Comment: It sounds like he wants us to "solve" meaning *compute* the multiplicative inverse of 9 modulo M for values of M between 2 and 10^9.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged wolfram-mathematica I assume you are asking in the context of Mathematica, in which case there is a built-in function to do this:

```
PowerMod[9,-1,m]
```

This will give you the inverse of 9, modulo m, for whatever value of m you want.

```
Table[PowerMod[9,-1,m],{m,2,1000}]
```

will produce:

```
PowerMod::ninv: 0 is not invertible modulo 3. >>
PowerMod::ninv: 3 is not invertible modulo 6. >>
PowerMod::ninv: 0 is not invertible modulo 9. >>
General::stop: Further output of PowerMod::ninv will be
  suppressed during this calculation. >>
{1, PowerMod[9, -1, 3], 1, 4, PowerMod[9, -1, 6], 4, 1, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 9], 9, 5, PowerMod[9, -1, 12], 3, 11, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 15], 9, 2, PowerMod[9, -1, 18], 17, 9, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 21], 5, 18, PowerMod[9, -1, 24], 14, 3, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 27], 25, 13, PowerMod[9, -1, 30], 7, 25, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 33], 19, 4, PowerMod[9, -1, 36], 33, 17, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 39], 9, 32, PowerMod[9, -1, 42], 24, 5, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 45], 41, 21, PowerMod[9, -1, 48], 11, 39, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 51], 29, 6, PowerMod[9, -1, 54], 49, 25, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 57], 13, 46, PowerMod[9, -1, 60], 34, 7, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 63], 57, 29, PowerMod[9, -1, 66], 15, 53, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 69], 39, 8, PowerMod[9, -1, 72], 65, 33, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 75], 17, 60, PowerMod[9, -1, 78], 44, 9, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 81], 73, 37, PowerMod[9, -1, 84], 19, 67, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 87], 49, 10, PowerMod[9, -1, 90], 81, 41, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 93], 21, 74, PowerMod[9, -1, 96], 54, 11, 
PowerMod[9, -1, 99], 89}
```

You can get rid of the invalid output from that list with:

```
Select[%, IntegerQ]
```

which gives:

```
{1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 9, 5, 3, 11, 9, 2, 17, 9, 5, 18, 14, 3, 25, 13, 7, 
 25, 19, 4, 33, 17, 9, 32, 24, 5, 41, 21, 11, 39, 29, 6, 49, 25, 13, 
 46, 34, 7, 57, 29, 15, 53, 39, 8, 65, 33, 17, 60, 44, 9, 73, 37, 19, 
 67, 49, 10, 81, 41, 21, 74, 54, 11, 89}
```

If you want to think smart, you can also organize this table better by skipping the elements that are not coprime with 9. One way to achieve this using more advanced Mathematica syntax would be:

```
Map[{#, PowerMod[9, -1, m]} &, Select[Range[100], GCD[#, 9] == 1 &]]
```

which gives you output:

```
{{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 4}, {7, 4}, {8, 1}, {10, 9}, {11, 5}, {13, 3},
 {14, 11}, {16, 9}, {17, 2}, {19, 17}, {20, 9}, {22, 5}, {23, 18},
 {25, 14}, {26, 3}, {28, 25}, {29, 13}, {31, 7}, {32, 25}, {34, 19},
 {35, 4}, {37, 33}, {38, 17}, {40, 9}, {41, 32}, {43, 24}, {44, 5},
 {46, 41}, {47, 21}, {49, 11}, {50, 39}, {52, 29}, {53, 6}, {55, 49},
 {56, 25}, {58, 13}, {59, 46}, {61, 34}, {62, 7}, {64, 57}, {65, 29},
 {67, 15}, {68, 53}, {70, 39}, {71, 8}, {73, 65}, {74, 33}, {76, 17},
 {77, 60}, {79, 44}, {80, 9}, {82, 73}, {83, 37}, {85, 19}, {86, 67},
 {88, 49}, {89, 10}, {91, 81}, {92, 41}, {94, 21}, {95, 74}, {97, 54},
 {98, 11}, {100, 89}}
```

That gives you a list of pairs, and each pair has the m value and then the inverse of 9 modulo that m value. For example, {61,34} is on that list, which means 9*34 is 1 mod 61. You can check that [this is right](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9*34%20mod%2061).